# Anonymous users can't view suggested edit source diff

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

While looking at [a suggested edit](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/126) on a site I'm not logged into, I noticed that anonymous users can't select the side-by-side Markdown diff option on that page because `full-anon.js` doesn't contain the definition for `StackExchange.suggestedEdits` that the page (unsuccessfully) tries to call `init()` on.

This is fairly minor since you can get basically the same view by looking at [the post's revision history](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/posts/876/revisions), which you'd have to pass through on your way to the suggested edit anyway if you were navigating by the relevant links. However, it would be nice if the suggested edit page worked like it's supposed to in this case, or if not that, at least didn't produce an error.

Also, while I'm nitpicking, I should point out that the icons for the Markdown diff in the revisions and suggested edits view are different as seen in the following screenshot and artist's rendition:

[image: alternate forms of the markdown diff view button] [image: a masterpiece]

Comment: This post is missing fancy [screenshots side-by-side with freehand circles](http://i.imgur.com/6sjR6.jpg).

Comment: +1 For the awesome art.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good call. I've moved the suggested edits JavaScript out of full.js to its own file; it'll be loaded on-demand now (next build). Besides fixing the issue you found, this also has the advantage that even for non-anonymous users it's not loaded when it's not needed – and *usually*, it's not.