# JS broken in Chrome 18

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image: http://i.imgur.com/CvSfX.png]

As the photo - `Variable 'n' has already been declared`.

I've tried clearing my cache, as well as using a new user profile with no extensions, but it doesn't work.

Might be useful to know so it can be fixed before more people are using Chrome (If it's SO's fault of course!)

Comment: This probably won't be addressed; [pre-release versions aren't supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/134300) and the developers usually ignore issues with them.

Comment: Hmm, I'm unable to reproduce this in Chrome 18 (although the error suggests a browser-independent issue anyway).

Comment: -1 For making me think my Chrome was horribly out of date...

Comment: I'm on the beta release and I too was like "18 WTF BBQ"

Comment: Chrome 18? Get you. @ZaphodBeeblebrox yeh I checked mine too

Comment: I am also facing this problem

Comment: Yeah, I'm having problems every other day it seems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is only a problem when the "Experimental Javascript" flag is enabled. I've disabled it [in chrome://flags](https://plus.google.com/113127438179392830442/posts/T615Md5JPQG), and now everything is fine again:

[image]

It should be noted that this flag also causes problems with Google's own Google Maps - I would disable it unless it's really needed.

Comment: There is already a bug report:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112675

Comment: The actual bug report for this particular issue is http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1942; this bug was fixed in http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/detail?r=10698, so in current Chrome versions, experimental JS shouldn't break anymore.

Answer (score 15):

While pre-release browsers really aren't supported, re-declared variables are a bug either way. I suppose Chrome's strict mode is getting stricter. I have removed (next build) a couple of re-declarations; none of them was called `n` in the current minified version, though (they're `j` and `q`). So I'll call this [status-maybe-completed](/questions/tagged/status-maybe-completed).

Comment: This seems an odd one doesn't it. I've tried refreshing/new profile etc etc but still no dice. Looking at the full.js, the minified version does have `var n=` in it 28 times, so perhaps the minification is a little lax on something that Chrome's strict mode chokes on. If it starts working again I'll reply here, as at this point I'd assume it's a Chrome bug.

Comment: FYI, the change has been built about 1.5 hours ago.

Comment: Working again (as of 16th Jan) - this can be marked as fixed.

Comment: I'm still experiencing this error on Chrome 18 for Mac OS X. It's a particularly irritating bug in that it prevents all Javascript, renderinging buttons for comments, voting, etc useless. I've had to switch to Firefox to post this.

Comment: Upon experimentation, I've discovered that this is only a problem when the "Experimental Javascript" flag is enabled. I've disabled it, and now everything is fine again.

Comment: I am still facing this problem

Comment: @LiamNewmarch: You are right. Problem lies in "Experimental Javascript" flag

Comment: The `n` still/again seems to be bothering some: [JavaScript error "Variable 'n' has already been declared" prevents UI interaction](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121177/javascript-error-prevents-ui-interaction).

Comment: @Arjan: Since this isn't causing issues in any supported browser, I'm not really worried. If someone tells me where exactly this error is happening, I'll fix it; otherwise, it'll have to wait until this appears in the Chrome release version so I can hunt it down myself.

Answer (score 5):

Pre-release browsers aren't supported (as Jeremy Banks already noted).

**However**, [balpha did recently make changes to *full.js*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118936/21960), where this error appears to be occurring. It may be related.

Comment: I make changes to that file all the time :)