# Stack Overflow JavaScript broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, javascript

Most, if not all, of the Stack Overflow JavaScript appears to be broken with the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Variable 'n' has already been declared

In `full.js` on Meta Stack Overflow and on some other script on Stack Overflow itself. Of course taking out the `use strict` at the beginning of the script should fix the issue - was that just added or something?

The serious implications here are that nobody using Chrome Canary 18.0.1017.0 with Experimental JavaScript turned on can upvote this question until this is fixed ;) Nor downvote nor flag, delete, comment... maybe it's time to add some more graceful degradation?

Comment: What browser/version are you using?

Comment: Previously fixed in [JS broken in Chrome 18](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118976/js-broken-in-chrome-18).

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Ah, okay. It's because I had the extra JavaScript features turned on. Well, still a bit of a bug as the question you linked to points out.

Comment: Can you give me the line number after de-minifying the code? (The "curly braces" button on the scripts tab of the chrome dev tools)

Comment: @balpha: Actually, no... it doesn't show up in the Scripts panel and so I can't get a line number by de-minifying it.

Comment: The accepted answer on [JS broken in Chrome 18](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118976/js-broken-in-chrome-18) claims *It should be noted that this flag also causes problems with Google's own Google Maps - I would disable it unless it's really needed.*