# Why is JS in Stackoverflow not working in Chromium 18

Tags: support, stack-overflow, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JS broken in Chrome 18](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118976/js-broken-in-chrome-18)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Variable 'c' has already been declared
ask:37 Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
ask:137 Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
ask:180 Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
ask:202 Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
ask:259 Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
```

I got these errors in the dev tools?
What can I do, because in Firefox works pretty!

Comment: Turn off "advanced JavaScript" in `chrome://flags`.

Comment: @minitech can you post this as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Stack Overflow's script, combined with `'use strict'`. Just turn off "advanced JavaScript" in `chrome://flags` to fix it.