# Cannot favorite a tag with Chrome

Tags: bug, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Favorite and ignored tags edit boxes on Stack Apps getting clipped in Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109450/favorite-and-ignored-tags-edit-boxes-on-stack-apps-getting-clipped-in-chrome)

I cannot add favorite tags with Chrome 19. Anyone else seeing this? I get the box and I can start typing and get auto completion. However I do not see the add button. I switched to IE 10 and it's there. Could it be because I'm an Windows 8?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this? Not seeing it (but on Windows 7).

Comment: You should still be able to add them by pressing enter.

Comment: No pressing enter does not work.

Comment: @Shog9 Added screenshot with border to show that it wasn't clipped artificially.

Comment: Try to disable: "Enable Experimental JavaScript" by going to chrome://flags/ and restart your browser.
It should help.

See related issues:

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118976/js-broken-in-chrome-18

Chromium bug report:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112675