# Could not start bounty - " Start bounty" button did not work

Tags: bug, bounties

I just tried setting bounty on one of the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583406/saving-audio-input-of-android-stock-speech-recognition-engine).

I tried using Chrome (19.0.1084.52) but could not (was later successful with IE 9).  When pressing "Start bounty" button on the last screen nothing would happen.

Is there a bug with Chrome?

OS is Win7/64bit. JavaScript is enabled:

[image]

And Experimental JavaScript (causing [trouble for others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118976/js-broken-in-chrome-18)) is not enabled.

Comment: Weird corporate firewall/proxy?

Comment: Hmmmm.... But if it works in IE could firewall/proxy be a problem?

Comment: If you use a different settings for each perhaps

Comment: No problem for me (Chrome 19/Ubuntu). Assuming you yet verified you have no js error, check your network tab in the console to see if a you get the result of a query. Otherwise, debug could be helpful. And deactivate extensions and popup blocking.

Comment: Chrome picks up same settings that IE uses (so it is not that).

Comment: Experimental JavaScript enabled? Don't. See [JS broken in Chrome 18](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118976/js-broken-in-chrome-18).

Comment: Hi @Arjan: Experimental JavaScript was disabled also.

Comment: Ah, re-reading your question you're saying that you entered all details (amount, reason, description maybe) and only the last step failed? Do you know how to peek into the JavaScript console and did you happen to look there? If things failed during the first (non-final) steps too, then maybe you can debug a bit more using that console. Of course, if only the last step failed, then debugging is a bit dangerous as it could set a new bounty if things don't fail...

Comment: Hi @Arjan, it failed on last step. Clicking on the final button did not do anything.  Next time I place bounty I will inspect more.

Comment: Are you using any user scripts?

Comment: I was not at the time.  I haven't tried since then to use start bounty.  I assume the problem was due to some bug in that particular version of Chrome as I did not observe it on other browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Probably, you had **disabled javascript**. Enable it and try again. Also there might be some conflicts with some chrome addons.

Comment: I check JavaScript and it was enabled.  Thanks for suggestion but that was not what was causing the problem.