# commenting (and lots of other commands) unavailable in chromium 18.0.1025.151

Tags: support, javascript, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JS broken in Chrome 18](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118976/js-broken-in-chrome-18)

when I click 'add comment', nothing happens. Same goes for:

```
-'Stack exchange' in the header to view messages/hot topics
-'show other means of login' on login page
-vote
-rich text edition isn't available
```

if it can be of any use, here's some console output:

```
stub.js:11Uncaught SyntaxError: Variable 'g' has already been declared
ask:21Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
ask:68Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
ask:76Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
ask:178Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
ask:219Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
ask:242Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
ask:269Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
ask:317Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
ask:374Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
```

Comment: Hit Ctrl+F5/clear your cache. Done.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118976/js-broken-in-chrome-18 (although that's [meta-tag:status-completed], so not VtC as a duplicate).

Comment: @UristMcBobby: I doubt that'll fix it. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118976/js-broken-in-chrome-18

Comment: @Matt that solved the problem, thanks. Cache cleaning didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several interesting aspects to this.

1. It turns out that variable redeclarations aren't actually illegal, even in strict mode. That suprised me a bit (I'd say this *usually* means there's a bug).
2. The variable `g` that has already been declared appears once as a formal parameter in the function definition, and once in a `var` declaration. So there's no double `var`.
3. This double `g` doesn't actually exist in our original code; it's only created by the minifier. The original unminfied version says:

   ```
   var fireConditionalCallbacks = function(objectName) {
       var callbacks = _conditionalCallbacks[objectName],
   ```

   The minified version (essentially) says:

   ```
   var n = function(g) {
       var g = a[g],
   ```

   Even if that's legal, as it appears to be the case, I'm not sure that's a good idea. I consider it highly confusing what the Closure compiler does there, but oh well…
4. Anyway, the most important point: The error you're seeing was a browser bug. More precisely, it was a bug in V8 (Chrome's JavaScript engine) that [was fixed a long time ago](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/detail?r=10698). In Chromium/Chrome 20, it doesn't appear, even with the experimental setting enabled. So just update your browser, and you should be fine (or leave experimental JS disabled).